# JavaScript to change appearance of elements on scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css

Okay, so I had this JavaScript and it was working perfectly fine.

```js
var header = document.getElementById('header');

window.onscroll = function () {
    "use strict";
    if (document.body.scrollTop >= 6) {
        header.className = 'header-colored';
    } else {
        header.className = 'header-transparent';
    }
};
```

But when I added another element to the script, it stopped working for some reason. Stopped working as in header stays transparent and arrow is always visible.

All relevant code (i believe):

```js
var header = document.getElementById('header');
var arrow = document.getElementsById('arrowToTop');
window.onscroll = function () {
    "use strict";
    if (document.body.scrollTop >= 6) {
        header.className = 'header-colored';
        arrow.className = 'arrow-visible';
    } else {
        header.className = 'header-transparent';
        arrow.className = 'arrow-transparent';
    }
};
```

```css
#header {
    position: fixed;
}

.header-transparent {
    background-color: transparent;
}

.header-colored {
    background-color: black;
    opacity: .9;
}

.toTop {
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    position: fixed;
}

  .arrow-visible {
    display: block;
}

.arrow-transparent {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
  <header id="header" class="header-transparent">
      <img src="Bilder/LOGO.png" alt="Blabla" style="width: 10%;">
         <ul id="navbar">
           <li><a href="#allText">home</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">business</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">technical</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">about us</a></li>
         </ul>
    </header>

  </div>
   <i class="material-icons" id="arrowToTop"><a class="toTop" href="#">keyboard_arrow_up</a></i>
  </div>
```

Does anyone know the reason why the script stopped working when I added a new variable and two extra lines of code?
Thanks!

Comment: were there any errors shown on your browser inspector console?

Comment: Nope, had one letter too much was the problem :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your declaration of `arrow` is plural.  Change this

```
  var arrow = document.getElementsById('arrowToTop');
```

To

```
 var arrow = document.getElementById('arrowToTop');
```

I don't see how you didn't get an error for that.  It's not a JS function.

Comment: Easy as that :) thanks! Would it work to change the 

    `arrow.className`

to 

     `arrow.id` by the way?

Comment: Glad I could help.  Please mark as answer if it solved your problem.  And no, you're using the CSS class of the element, so you need to set that class to the className object, not the ID.

Comment: Yep, marked it now! And yes, I'd change the css from class to ID of course. Problem with using class is that the element needs to have the `material-icons` class to display the icon properly. When I change it, the text `arrow_up_icon` is displayed instead of the arrow-icon.